# unaccessible and inaccessible

Tags: word-usage, difference

inaccesible and unaccessible?
what is the difference between the two and how would they be chosen for a sentence. Are both words used equally or is there a certain rule that decides wich is used?

Comment: See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/507387/is-there-a-difference-between-unaccessible-and-inaccessible

Answer (score 1):

Inaccessible is much more common, but it seems that unaccessible is sometimes used in the same places and it is listed in some online dictionaries. I looked it up in my dictionary and there is no entry for "unaccessible". I guess "unaccessible" is a word some native/non-native speakers have wrongly used to an extent that some online dictionaries have felt the need to define it. It's better not to use a non-standard word and only use it when it's become common enough to be included in all dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

If you always use **inaccessible**, you'll never go wrong and you won't have to debate whether "unaccessible" is even a real word.